# How to add Web API to Azure AD application through power shell or Azure CLI

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

i am working an automation of configure App registration in Azure AD with Powers hell. i just used this link to register app with power shell command: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-Active-Directory-Videos-Demos/ManageAppsAzureADPowerShell?view=azureadps-2.0.

but now i need to add some Web API's to the particular app through power shell or Azure CLI commands(Web API means going to app in that click on Required permissions then click add + for select an API like(Power BI, Skype, Office 365, Microsoft Graph) kind of those with power shell, please let me know if anybody did it, thanks.

Comment: I am able to register an Native app in Azure AD through .NET Framework and also add permissions and grant permissions through the same script but i need to add Web app instead of Native app and it's asking to insert Client Secret, please let me know where to modify it, Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/krishnareddyg/Azure-Automation

Comment: while running script for Web app getting an below errorException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.\r\nTrace ID: f5b4db58-36f3-49df-8234-191d82050100\r\nCorrelation ID: a79fa9e7-1253-4a82-a5bd-4ead9bc05cec\r\nTimestamp: 2017-07-31 23:32:32Z","error_codes":[70002],"timestamp":"2017-07-31 23:32:32Z","trace_id":"f5b4db58-36f3-49df-8234-191d82050100","correlation_id":"a79fa9e7-1253-4a82-a5bd-4ead9bc05cec"}